# Identify if at least one row with given condition exists

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Employee table has ID and NAME columns. Names can be repeated. I want to find out if there is at least one row with name like 'kaushik%'.

So query should return true/false or 1/0.

Is it possible to find it using single query.
If we try something like

```
select count(1) from employee where name like 'kaushik%'
```

in this case it does not return true/false. 
Also we are iterating over all the records in table. Is there way in simple SQL such that whenever first record which satisfies condition is fetched, it should stop checking further records.
Or such thing can only be handled in Pl/SQL block ?

EDIT *
First approach provided by Justin looks correct answer

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE name like 'kaushik%' AND rownum = 1
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't really have a Boolean data type.

Comment: you can just add rownum to your query i.e. select count(1) from employee where name like 'kaushik%' and rownum = 1; or use rownum < 2;

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Commonly, you'd express this as either

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM employee
 WHERE name like 'kaushik%'
   AND rownum = 1
```

where the `rownum = 1` predicate allows Oracle to stop looking as soon as it finds the first matching row or

```
SELECT 1
  FROM dual
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM employee
                WHERE name like 'kaushik%' )
```

where the `EXISTS` clause allows Oracle to stop looking as soon as it finds the first matching row.

The first approach is a bit more compact but, to my eye, the second approach is a bit more clear since you really are looking to determine whether a particular row exists rather than trying to count something.  But the first approach is pretty easy to understand as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you added the `rownum = 1` in the first query. The query will return one row anyway, because of the aggregation `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @ypercube the query will stop scanning after first match as Justin explained.

Comment: Another difference is that the `SELECT COUNT(*)` version will return 0 for no result, whereas the `SELECT 1` version will raise NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: @Justin In the second approach, the subquery will go over all the records of employee table, before the outer query runs. So first approach correct to me than second. Am I right ?

Comment: @KaushikLele - Both queries will stop processing as soon as the first matching row is found.  As I said in my answer, when you use the `EXISTS` clause, Oracle knows that it can stop evaluating the query in the `EXISTS` clause as soon as it returns a row.

Comment: what is `dual`?

Comment: @picheto - `dual` is a special table (or pseudo-table) that always exists and always has exactly one row.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
select max(case when name like 'kraushik%' then 1 else 0 end)
from employee
```

Or, what might be more efficient since `like` can use indexes:

```
select count(x)
from (select 1 as x
      from employee
      where name like 'kraushik%'
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

since you require that the sql query should return 1 or 0, then you can try the following query :-

```
select count(1) from dual 
where exists(SELECT 1 
             FROM employee
             WHERE name like 'kaushik%')
```

Since the above query uses Exists, then it will scan the employee table and as soon as it encounters the first record where name matches "kaushik", it will return 1 (without scanning the rest of the table). If none of the records match, then it will return 0.

Comment: As per my understanding, inner query will run first scanning over all the records of employee and returning a temporary table. And then outer query will run to check if inner query has return anything ? Am I right ?  Or "Exists" clause behaves diferently.

Comment: nope...the exists clause behaves differently....the inner query will run first and as soon as the first match in the employee table is found, it will return (without scanning any further) and the outer query will then run...

Comment: can you give me any link of Oracle documentation which explains Exists clause. So that I can confirm above explaination.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 
 where exists ( select name 
                  from employee 
                  where name like 'kaushik%'
               )
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to have a `from dual` after the `select 1`

Comment: well sorry i did not.. i do not even know what that means 2 b honest

Comment: Oracle requires a `FROM` clause in every SQL statement..  Unlike, say, Postgres where `select 1;` is a perfectly valid statement.

Comment: alrite. i just meant it in a SQL way to stop looking when u find the first record n tested the statement on SQL Server before posting. im sorry about that, have no hands on with Oracle..