# Check if records exist in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to check if records exist in my table. I found out that the most efficient way is to use the DUAL table. However, I am not 100% sure on how this method works. I have a table which contains thousands of records (almost half a million). Is there any major difference between these two methods, keeping in mind that a lot of records are present in the table:

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT 1
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
             FROM MY_TABLE
             WHERE MY_COLUMN_PK = 'MY_VALUE'
             AND MY_COLUMN = 'MY_VALUE')
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT 1
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
             FROM MY_TABLE
             WHERE MY_COLUMN_PK = 'MY_VALUE'
             AND MY_COLUMN = 'MY_VALUE'
             AND ROWNUM=1)
```

I have executed both queries in my database client software and both queries had similar execution times.

**Note:** `MY_COLUMN_PK` is the primary key of my table while `MY_COLUMN` isn't a primary key and doesn't have an index.

Comment: "Method 2"  is more effective.

Comment: We can't say without knowing which primary and unique keys you have.

Comment: @HardikVinzava Method 1 is selecting all the records in the table while Method 2 is selecting only the first records. I know that Method 2 is more effective but why am I getting the same execution times?

Comment: Because you are querying using the primary key. Oracle knows that if there is a match it will only be for 1 row anyway.

Comment: But I am not using only the primary key in the where clause

Comment: That's what I asked?! But see my answer, it covers both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `my_column` forms a unique or primary key,

```
select 1
from my_table
where my_column = 'my_value';
```

is enough.

If the column to check is not unique, then you only need to check for the existence of 1 row. In this case:

```
select /*+ first_rows */ 1
from my_table
where my_column = 'my_value'
and rownum <= 1;
```

is best. The use of the `first_rows` hint was necessary in older versions of Oracle but is probably unnecessary these days. It tells the optimizer that we want to optimize to get rows back as fast as possible (because we only want 1 row anyway).

In addition, `rownum = 1` is OK too, but I always write my checks on `rownum` as being less than or equal to a value to remind me that I can never do `rownum > n`...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566910/identify-if-at-least-one-row-with-given-condition-exisits). Both methods in the above question are identical since the `EXISTS` clause is being used. As explained by Justin Cave in the question attached,  "the `EXISTS` clause allows Oracle to stop looking as soon as it finds the first matching row".